# How to split the tags automatically by special keyword?

Tags: angular, ngx-chips

I am developing an Angular 2+ web application in which I would like to copy the sentence like "**User 1 | User 2 | User 3**" in the text box and once I have copied , I expect it to be automatically converted into tags like in the picture below

[image]

**Please notice that I have my sentence separated by pipe(|) symbol.**

I have tried to use [ngx-chips](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-chips) plugin and used `pasteSplitPattern-[?string | RegExp]`

But my tag is displayed like below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to split your string something like that:

```
const tags = event.value.trim().split('|');
```

And then you'll be able to handle **tags** array (["User 1 ", " User 2 ", " User 3"]).

Depends on what do you need, you can use ***ngFor** or write additional logic in component.

That's the example with spitting on `Space`. You can change it to `|` :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chipses?file=app/chips-autocomplete-example.ts

Comment: As we do use ngx-chips plugin , we have to recognize automatically when user is copied into the text box and change them as tags. How to make it possible ?

Comment: Is this link shows the example of ngx-chips plugin ?

Comment: It shows the logic you have to implement. It doesn't matter what plugin is used.